# jQuery set different date on many inputs based on the nearest input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many date-type inputs (one for initial date and one for a new date for each stage) and a number-type input which should define how many days to add to all that "new date" inputs based on "old date" value of the nearest input. Now it changes all dates based on the first "old date" input value.

```js
function calcNewDate() {
  var addDays = parseInt($('#chdn').val());
  $('.newDate').val(formatDate(new Date($('.oldDate').val()).setDate(new Date($('.oldDate').val()).getDate() + addDays)));
}

function formatDate(date) {
  var d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Days to add to each newDate: <input id="chdn" type="number" onchange="calcNewDate();" onkeyup="calcNewDate();" />
<div class="stage">
  <h4>Stage #1</h4>
  Old date - <input class="oldDate" type="date" value="2017-06-01" disabled> New date - <input class="newDate" type="date" disabled>
</div>
<div class="stage">
  <h4>Stage #2</h4>
  Old date - <input class="oldDate" type="date" value="2017-08-15" disabled> New date - <input class="newDate" type="date" disabled>
</div>
<!-- here could be more stages -->
```

Solution:

```
$('.newDate').each(function(){
$(this).val(formatDate(new Date($(this).prevAll('.oldDate').val()).setDate(new Date($(this).prevAll('.oldDate').val()).getDate() + parseInt($('#chdn').val()))));
});
```

Thanks to @Zenoo

Comment: dont use inline event handlers

Comment: The problem is that you are targeting `.oldDate` which will return a list of all the elements with `.oldDate`. `.val()` will return the value of the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multiple `.newDate`, you'll need to loop through them and access each one's `.oldDate` using jQuery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`.prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) methods :

```
$('.newDate').each(function(){
  $(this).val(formatDate(new Date().setDate(new Date($(this).prevAll('.oldDate').val()).getDate() + addDays)));
});
```

***Demo:***

```js
function calcNewDate() {
  const addDays = +$('#chdn').val();
  $('.newDate').each(function(){
    $(this).val(formatDate(new Date().setDate(new Date($(this).prevAll('.oldDate').val()).getDate() + addDays)));
  });
}

function formatDate(date) {
  var d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Days to add to each newDate: <input id="chdn" type="number" onchange="calcNewDate();" onkeyup="calcNewDate();" />
<div class="stage">
  <h4>Stage #1</h4>
  Old date - <input class="oldDate" type="date" value="2017-06-01" disabled> New date - <input class="newDate" type="date" disabled>
</div>
<div class="stage">
  <h4>Stage #2</h4>
  Old date - <input class="oldDate" type="date" value="2017-08-15" disabled> New date - <input class="newDate" type="date" disabled>
</div>
<!-- here could be more stages -->
```